# Python - Sqlite insert tuple without the autoincrement primary key value

Tags: python, sqlite

I create a table with primary key and autoincrement.

```
with open('RAND.xml', "rb") as f, sqlite3.connect("race.db") as connection:
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS race(RaceID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,R_Number    INT, R_KEY INT,\
        R_NAME TEXT, R_AGE INT, R_DIST TEXT, R_CLASS, M_ID INT)""")
```

I want to then insert a tuple which of course has 1 less number than the total columns because the first is autoincrement.

```
 sql_data = tuple(b)
    c.executemany('insert into race values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', b)
```

How do I stop this error.

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table race has 8 columns but 7 values were supplied
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's extremely bad practice to assume a specific ordering on the columns. Some DBA might come along and modify the table, breaking your SQL statements. Secondly, an autoincrement value will only be used if you don't specify a value for the field in your `INSERT` statement - if you give a value, that value will be stored in the new row.

If you amend the code to read

```
c.executemany('''insert into
            race(R_number, R_KEY, R_NAME, R_AGE, R_DIST, R_CLASS, M_ID)
            values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',
            sql_data)
```

you should find that everything works as expected.

Comment: I may have misled you slightly, as I believe some databses will generate an autoincrement value if you try to store a NULL in the primary key field (since NULL is never a valid primary key).

Comment: Yes it still errors. λ python xml_race.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml_race.py", line 78, in <module>
    values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', sql_data)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 7, and there are 6 supplied. Will try add a null in

Comment: The clear implication of that error message is than `len(sql_data) != 7` - can you check that with a `print` to verify?

Answer (score 1):

From the [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

> If the `column-name` list after `table-name` is omitted then the number of values inserted into each row must be the same as the number of columns in the table.

`RaceID` is a column in the table, so it is expected to be present when you're doing an `INSERT` without explicitly naming the columns. You can get the desired behavior (assign `RaceID` the next autoincrement value) by passing an SQLite `NULL` value in that column, which in Python is `None`:

```
sql_data = tuple((None,) + a for a in b)
c.executemany('insert into race values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', sql_data)
```

*The above assumes `b` is a sequence of sequences of parameters for your `executemany` statement and attempts to prepend `None` to each sub-sequence. Modify as necessary for your code.*