# How do I pass variables in SQL3 python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to pass a variable through an SQL statement but it isn't working

One of my columns in SQL is auto-increment however, the program is still asking for a value to input.

```
CREATE TABLE "Animes" (
    "ID"    INTEGER,
    "Name"  TEXT,
    "GenreID"   INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("GenreID") REFERENCES "Genres"("ID"),
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

The code I have tried so far:

```
name = "Boruto"
genreid = 1
c.execute('''INSERT INTO Animes VALUES(?,?)''',(name,genreid))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324630/python-sqlite-insert-tuple-without-the-autoincrement-primary-key-value) to a related question about inserting with auto-increment fields. Note the comment about not assuming the order of the columns.

Comment: Try to do `'INSERT INTO Animes(Name, GenreID) VALUES(?, ?)'`, which indicates the specific columns that you are adding and not the whole table.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out. Thanks anyway